# Comparar datas no sql

Tags: php, mysql

No meu banco tenho o campo com datetime current_timestamp na tabela acesso. Preciso exibir a quantidade que cada dispositivo acessou o site, seja computador, ios ou android, cada vez que um deles acessa, o campo correspondente recebe 1, assim eu preciso contar no dia quantas vezes o site obteve acesso de cada dispositivo, problema é: como eu converto o datetime na query pra comparar só a data sem a hora? 
Fiz dessa maneira mas funcionou ontem, mas o os dados do acesso eram de ontem, hoje já deu problema.

```
<?php
    $select= "SELECT distinct CAST(data_acesso AS DATE) FROM tbl_acesso";
    $result_select= $conn->query($select);
    while($col = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_select)):
        $data = $col['data'];
        $data_create = date_create($data);
        $data_format = date_format($data_create, "Y-m-d");

        //selecionando site
        $selectSite = "SELECT site FROM tbl_acesso WHERE CAST(data_acesso as DATE) = '$data_format' AND site IS NOT NULL ";
        $resultadoSite = $conn->query($selectSite);
        $site = mysqli_num_rows($resultadoSite);

        //selecionando ios
        $selectIos = "SELECT ios FROM tbl_acesso WHERE CAST(data_acesso as DATE) = '$data_format' AND ios IS NOT NULL";
        $resultadoIos = $conn->query($selectIos);
        $ios = mysqli_num_rows($resultadoIos);

        //selecionando android
        $selectAndroid = "SELECT android FROM tbl_acesso WHERE CAST(data_acesso as DATE) = '$data_format' AND android IS NOT NULL";
        $resultadoAndroid = $conn->query($selectAndroid);
        $android = mysqli_num_rows($resultadoAndroid);
?>
```

Comment: é melhor você remover essa edição e adicionar uma resposta.. assim você pode marcá-la como aceita e a pergunta não fica aberta

Comment: entendi, vou fazer isso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O dado deve ser um datetime ou smalldatetime, então ele guarda ambos os valores. Você pode fazer assim:

```
convert(date,@data1) = convert(date,@data2)
```

Assim você compara ignorando horas pois ambas são convertidos de DATETIME para DATE (sem hora).

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: No caso do seu banco, acho que tem que ser  cast(data_acesso as date) = cast('$data_formatada',date)

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi fazendo isso aqui galera

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(data_acesso, '%Y-%m-%d') AS data_acesso FROM tbl_acesso;
```

No sgbd dava certo, mas no php não ia pq precisava de um alias.